# Meaning of 19th-century American parlour games

Tags: meaning

I would really appreciate it if someone could explain to me the meaning of three American parlour games of the 19th century.

I am currently translating a novel where these games are mentioned and would like to provide a footnote for the readers saying how exactly those games were played. The names of the games (which are for children) are Post Office and Hunt the Keyhole. I am wondering whether there might be another version of the Post Office game, apart from the one mentioned in Wikipedia (i.e. suitable for children). As to the Hunt the Keyhole, Google returns no information about that game at all.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_%28game%29

Comment: http://www.victoriaspast.com/ParlorGames/parlor_games.htm#The%20Dumb%20Orator

Comment: "Hunt the keyhole" appears to be an adult's "game", played when they're so drunk the key won't go into the slot.

Comment: I've looked up the Post Office on Wikipedia before posting this question, but it seemed a bit too adult to be a children's game. That's why I decided to ask here, maybe there is some other version of that game. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I never played Post Office as a child, but it was always my understanding that it was a kissing game.

Comment: @hope_clearwater In Britain it is called *Postman's Knock*, and nowadays is extremely dated. It used to be a children's game, causing much hilarity among older children (aged about 8 to 11) for whom the opposite sex are usually the lowest form of life. Amid jeers from his friends, John would cringe at the thought of having to kiss Jenny, and end up giving her the lightest of kisses on some unexposed part of her i.e on her clothing. But as the game progresses into an adult form, it becomes far more risqué.

Comment: This question probably belongs on history.se- it's not really about English language usage.

Comment: @jejorda2 I've posted it there, as well. I would say that this question is somewhere on the borderline between history and the English language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about finding out the rules for games, not about English Language per se.

Comment: @Hellion Then, could you maybe suggest which community is better for this kind of question? History.se?

Comment: @hope_clearwater History.SE does seem like the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

[Post office](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_(game)):

> - is a kissing game played by boys and girls at parties. It has been referred to in United States popular culture since at least the 1880's.

[The Dumb Orator](http://www.victoriaspast.com/ParlorGames/parlor_games.htm#top) :

> - This is a very amusing performance, enacted by two persons for the benefit of the rest of the company. One of the two recites a speech, or any popular piece of declamation- My name is Norval," or the like - keeping all the while perfectly motionless, and without a quiver upon his countenance, while the other, standing silent by his side, gesticulates furiously, according to the emotions called up by the passage recited.

(www.victoriaspast.com/ParlorGames)

Comment: Thank you for your response! Still, I am not sure whether this interpretation of the Post Office game is for children? It seems like it's rather for young adults. Do you think there might be another version of this game for kids?

Comment: @hope_clearwater - the game has some variations as you can see from the site. But I'd not  rule out the fact that children could mimic a game for more grown-up people.